# How to speed-up first call to ASP.NET web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, mono

I have a very basic ASP.NET web-service.

It works, however the first call takes 10 seconds - while subsequent calls happen instantly.

I realize its being JIT compiled, therefore I'm trying to understand how pre-compile things to speed up the first call.

So far here is what I have done.

The web-service file is: *HelloWorldService.cs*:

```
using System.Web.Services;
namespace MyService
{
  public class HelloWorldService: WebService
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
      return "Hello World";
    }
  }
}
```

I have compiled this using `gmcs -target:library HelloWorldService.cs -r:System.Web.Services`

I've placed the resulting `HelloWorldService.dll` file inside the /bin directory of the webroot.

Next, I've created the `HelloWorld.asmx`-stub file as follows:

```
<%@WebService Language="C#" Class="MyService.HelloWorldService"%>
```

This works, but as said earlier the first call takes 10-15 seconds to complete...although subsequent calls work fine.

In researching, I've seen references that you need to use the `sgen` utility to create a serialized XML file.

I've used that file by running:

```
sgen HelloWorldService.dll
```

which creates a file name `HelloWorldService.XmlSerializers.dll` and put that also in the `/bin` directory.

However, none of this has helped.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Perhaps you could adjust the application settings in IIS so it keeps it running longer? That way you only have this issue the first time?

Comment: Perhaps work around the issue with a simple script to 'ping' the website when the unit starts up, forcing compilation straight away?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you make sure your production service almost never stops. Then there is no "first" request, because it will only re-compile if you need to make a change. When you do need to make a change in production (or restart the server), you schedule it for during low use times. If there is no acceptable low use time, you use a web farm, and remove the server from the farm during the update and make your "first" request to the updated server as part of the update, before returning it back to the farm.

Comment: I should explain a little of the use case: This is an embedded project (running linux / arm / mono). The device itself is a small unit which will be attached to various manufacturing equipment. It exposes the status of the machine as a web-service so that information can be collected by a master server and used elsewhere. Due to how it will be used, it will often be powered-off and on -- resulting in many "first calls".

Comment: +1 as it answers question as asked. @freetx, you probably should ask separate question with this remark - no one excepts generic question on web services have such an interesting restriction.

Answer (score 2):

i have been working with .Net for years now, and i have yet to find something to speed up the very very first ever call to a web service, or web application (web sites on the other hand, are great, since they compile pages one by one as they are called, which makes things much faster)...

The very very first call always compiles everything, and yes, it takes time... but after that, if you setup IIS to not "sleep application pool after X time", it's fine.

What i've grown custom to do myself, is every time i publish a site or web service, i call it myself in my browser, before giving the "all clear" message to those involved... that way they get insta-service from that point on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even know if it applies to ASP.NET, but since you tagged the question with #mono, perhaps you should take a look at this (in case you haven't already): http://www.mono-project.com/AOT

Comment: Yes, I independently found that as well. But like you, don't exactly understand how you would get the resulting .so files to get picked up by ASP in this context. I'm an ASP noob though, so it could be obvious but I just don't get it.